# Ajax call returns error after 63 sec in android version 4.1.x

Tags: ajax, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am making an ajax call to server using POST method. As response size is 8-10 GB data it takes 2-3 minutes to return response. Ajax wait for response only in android 4.4 device, but in device with android version 4.1.X it throws error response after 63 sec even if the request is processing at backend.

I tested it in 
Nexus 5 (android 4.4) - working fine,
Galaxy core (android 4.1.2) - throws error

Please let me know if any one has solution for the problem

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `timeout` in ajax call.